# Best practictes - Should I store the URL of the link in the index?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Today I don't store the URL of my pages in the index of Azure Search. I am still coping what is the best solution to solve this. So, when a search is returned from Azure Search, all I receive is the Id and no URL to the pages :/.

So, to retrieve the URL, what would be a proper way to solve this?

1. Store the urls in the index and retrieve it with the search;
2. Do an additional query to the database with the data returned from Azure Search and retrieve the URL.
3. ???

THANKS

Comment: Hi Fernando, what stopping you from storing the URL in the index? It seems like solution 1. would be the easiest one. You can mark the new field with the URL as retrievable and not searchable to exclude it from the inverted index.

Comment: My concern is that, currently, I am not storing it in the database, since I am calculating it in the c#. Example: public string Url => "/person/" + SocialSecurity;
Since I am using Sql Integrated Change Tracking for change detection, I would need to add this extra column to the database and replicate it in the index. Would this be worth?

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining this. If you want to use Indexers to populate and update your index then you'd have to add a new column to the database. Alternatively, you can use our .Net SDK to add the field with the URL to the documents already in your index (merge option: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798930.aspx). For the reasons Pablo mentioned below, you should optimize for now having to join data coming from different sources at query time. The details how to achieve that are specific to your application. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to store enough information in the search index to avoid an extra hit to a different database/store if possible.

If your URLs follow a consistent pattern and only a part changes (e.g. the document id or something like that), you can store only the variable part and construct the final URL when rendering results. If your URLs cannot be turned into a pattern, you can just store the whole URL in a field in the Azure Search index.

When storing data used for presentation (URLs, external keys, etc.) it's a good idea to ensure you disable all options related to fast search/filtering (searchable, filterable, sortable, facetable, etc.) and only leave retrievable enabled. That way you minimize the use of resources caused by the extra field, but you have the data at hand to avoid an extra roundtrip during results rendering.